# E: Clean of / is not supported

Tags: linux-mint, apt

When i try command like `sudo apt-get autoclean` or `sudo apt-get clean` i get an error `E: Clean of / is not supported`.

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading Package Lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
E: Clean of / is not supported

$ apt-config dump | fgrep Dir::Cache
Dir::Cache "";
Dir::Cache::archives "";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "srcpkgcache.bin";
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "pkgcache.bin";
```

I'm using Linux Mint

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sarah
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 Sarah"
```

Any suggestion to fix that please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have modified your `apt` configuration:

```
Dir::Cache "";
Dir::Cache::archives "";
```

Here are the correct values:

```
Dir::Cache "var/cache/apt/";
Dir::Cache::archives "archives/";
```

Since `apt` prepends a `/` to `Dir::Cache`, it is refusing to clean`/` as reported in its error message. Fix your configuration in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`
and/or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`